# Get the text of a python script that is passed via the `-c` option

Tags: python

If I run a python script via `python foo.py` then I can get the contents of the script by reading the file `sys.argv[0]`. Is it possible to get the contents of the script (e.g., as a string) if the script is passed to the python interpreter via `python -c "$(cat foo.py)"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. As far as I know, It wont be possible. When you call "$(cat foo.py)", shell will get only the contents and the reference is lost.

Comment: I don't need the reference, just the contents, if the contents of the script are available during execution.